# Как решить данный пример задачи

Tags: c#

Вот нашел такую задачку:

**1 * 2 / 3 * 4 / 5 * 6 / … / 99 * 100**

Написал цикл только до того что он умножает  1 * 2 но не могу понять как мне теперь результат умножение поделить на 3 и тд.

```
 double sum1 = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            sum1 *= i;
           
        };
```

обьясните пожалуйста

Comment: В цикле шагай на двойку, за один шаг делай одно умножение и одно деление. Ну и начинать с нуля - это сразу всё запороть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double sum = 1;
for(int i = 2; i <= 99; i+=2)
{
    sum *= i;
    sum /= i + 1;
}
```